# Get Attribute Values From Child Element With No ID - JQuery

Tags: attributes, children

Lets say I have this code:

```
<div id="Element_1" class="draggable">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Text Here" style="width:300px;">
</div>
<div id="Element_2" class="draggable">
<textarea placeholder="Enter Your Text Here" style="width:400px;height:200px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is get the element attribute values, from the child of the "div" and also the "Type" (Input/Tagname) so I can store the values in variables.

Currently I can get the element and store in a Var, this is the code I have:

```
$(".draggable").live("click",function(){
    var SelectedID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("*").removeClass("selected");   
    var Element = $("#"+SelectedID,":first-child").addClass("selected").html();

    PlaceholderPropValue = $(element).attr("placeholder");
    StylesPropValue = $(element).attr("style");
    WidthProp = StylesProp.match(/(width:)([0-9].*?)(?=px;)/)[2];
    HeightProp = StylesProp.match(/(height:)([0-9].*?)(?=px;)/)[2];
    alert(PlaceholderPropValue+ " " +WidthProp+ " " +HeightProp);
});
```

Thanks!

Carl

Comment: Your question is missing crucial information. What programming language/library/framework do you use to access the data? Is it JavaScript, C++, .Net, XMLNuke, Xerces, ...

Also add some code that shows how you read in the data, so we know where to start from. Btw: XML is not code, it's data.

Comment: ohh ye sorry!! Haha JQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is kind of overkill.

1. .live() is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and totally removed in 1.9, jquery documentation says you should use .on() instead.
2. Everything is simple. You can try something like:

> ```
> $('.draggable').click(function(){
>     var $element = $(this).children();
>     var width = parseInt($element.width());
>     var height = parseInt($element.height());
>     var placeholder = $element.attr('placeholder');  
>     alert(placeholder+ " " +width+ " " +height);
> })
> ```

- [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method normally return set of element's children but there are only one in your example, so it's ok.
- .width() and .height() returns values like "300px", so we use parseInt() to make int values.
- .click(handler) is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )

Comment: Thank You! Thats great! How do I get the "TagName" or "Type"?

Comment: Its ok i got it! Thanks